# memory access when writing a linux kernel module in assembler

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel, nasm, kernel-module

i try writing a kernel module in assembler. In one time i needed a global vars. I define a dword in .data (or .bss) section, and in init function i try add 1 to var. My program seccesfully make, but insmod sey me:

```
$ sudo insmod ./test.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module ./test.ko: Invalid module format
```

it's my assembler code in nasm:

```
[bits 64]

global init
global cleanup

extern printk

section .data
    init_mess db "Hello!", 10, 0
    g_var dd 0

section .text

init:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    inc dword [g_var]

    mov rdi, init_mess
    xor rax, rax
    call printk

    xor rax, rax
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret

cleanup:
    xor rax, rax
    ret
```

if i write adding in C code, all work good:

```
static i = 0;
static int  __init main_init(void)    { i++; return init(); }
```

But in this `objdump -d test.ko` write a very stainght code for me:

```
0000000000000000 <init_module>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   ff 05 00 00 00 00       incl   0x0(%rip)        # 7 <init_module+0x7>
   7:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   a:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  f <init_module+0xf>
   f:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  10:   c3                      retq
```

What does this mean (incl 0x0(%rip))? How can I access memory? Please, help me :)
(My system is archlinux x86_64)

my C code for correct make a module:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

MODULE_AUTHOR("Actics");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Description");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

extern int init(void);
extern int cleanup(void);

static int  __init main_init(void)    { return init(); }
static void __exit main_cleanup(void) { cleanup(); }

module_init(main_init);
module_exit(main_cleanup);
```

and my Makefile:

```
obj-m := test.o
test-objs := inthan.o module.o
KVERSION = $(shell uname -r)
inthan.o: inthan.asm
    nasm -f elf64 -o $@ $^

build:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kernel mode lives in the "negative" (ie. top) part of the address space, where 32 bit absolute addresses can not be used (because they are not sign-extended). As you have noticed, gcc uses rip-relative addresses to work around this problem which gives offsets from the current instruction pointer. You can make nasm do the same by using the `DEFAULT REL` directive. See the [relevant section in the nasm documentation](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc6.html#section-6.2).

Comment: Magic!) Thank you very mush, it's work! I don't know, how it's work, but i necessarily read moar about this.

Answer (score 1):

you can always use [inline assembly](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html)

```
 asm("add %3,%1 ; sbb %0,%0 ; cmp %1,%4 ; sbb $0,%0"             \
 54             : "=&r" (flag), "=r" (roksum)                               \
 55             : "1" (addr), "g" ((long)(size)),                           \
 56               "rm" (limit));
```

Comment: unfortunately, i can't use inline assembler(